# Contrator, contractee... and disease?

Tags: grammar, etymology

On my security card at work is written "Contractor" in big, bold, capital letters.
A thought just crossed my mind (as I work for a medical company):

If I am the contractor, am I the one passing the disease to others? Is it correct to call the other side of the contract the Contractee?

And what does it say about our work relations, if this is how they see me? :-)

Comment: Contractee is correct.

Comment: @Frank - Just to add some confusion: a contract has two active participants, so logically both are Contractors. Contractee would be a third party who was allocated according to the conditions in a contract. In many cases, where an agency is involved, that would mean that the person who is sent to do the work should really be called the Contractee. That is not the normal terminology, as the OP's card indicates. I would normally call the other party of such a temporary employment contract the _Client_.

Comment: And by the way, neither my dictionary nor the spell-checker contain the word _contractee_.

Comment: And (from my own experience in a similar position) the client usually does regard contractors as a source of disease... ;-)

Comment: @DavidR You'll need a legal dictionary. In a normal contract one party creates the contract and offers it for fulfilment, they are the contractee. The party who enters the contract is the contractor. In an ABC contract where A is a person and B & C are usually companies, A is an employee (with a contract of employment) of B, the contract to supply work is between B and C. C is the contractee (they make the contract), B is the contractor (they enter into the contract with C) and A is not part of that contract. A is what is known as a 'temp' hence 'temping'.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I stand corrected. My command of legalese is limited, although I have at various times had all 3 roles (sort of) and on some occasions also involving an additional party (where I was an employee of (my) company, which had a contract with an agency to supply my skills via another contract to another company) - we would normally be referred to in layman's terms as _consultant_ (or _contractor_, like the OP), _consultancy_, _agency_ and _client_ respectively.

Comment: @DavidR No need to stand corrected, layman's terms are much more common that the legal terms and often make more sense. If the user hadn't suggested _contractee_ I probably wouldn't have suggested it either.